# So LWP::UserAgent can automatically detect the charset?

Tags: perl, encoding, lwp

```
  our $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
  my $response = $ua->get($url);
  if($response->is_success) {
    my $perl_hash_or_arrayref = decode_json(encode("UTF-8", $response->decoded_content));
```

The above code converts the response to **UTF-8** encoding,without the need to tell it which encoding the response is using.

I asume this may fail under certain cases.

How can I explicitly tell `LWP::UserAgent` the response encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the docs for `decoded_content` in [`HTTP::Message`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aMessage):

> $mess->decoded_content( %options )
>
> ```
>     Returns the content with any Content-Encoding undone and for
>  textual content the raw content encoded to Perl's Unicode strings.
>  If the Content-Encoding or charset of the message is unknown this
>  method will fail by returning undef.
>
>     The following options can be specified.
>
>     charset
>
>         This override the charset parameter for text content. The value
>  none can used to suppress decoding of the charset.
> ```

Comment: `If the Content-Encoding or charset of the message is unknown this
 method will fail by returning undef.`,but actually it works,just that I don't know the internals.

Comment: @new_perl: LWP simply looks at the `Content-Encoding` and `Charset` HTTP headers sent by the HTTP server you are talking to.